# Find density function for $Y = e^X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> $X$ is a continuous random variable. Let $Y= e^X$. Find the density function of $Y$ in terms of density function of $X$.

if $X$ is continuous random variable then $Y$ is too. So we know that
$$ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) dx= 1  $$
so
$$ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f_Y(y) dy = 1  = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f_{e^X}(y) dy $$ But don't see how I can proceed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Assuming $y \ge 0$, we have
$$
F_Y(y)
 = \mathbb{P}[ Y \le y]
 = \mathbb{P}\left[ e^X \le y\right]
 = \mathbb{P}[ X \le \ln(y) ]
$$
Can you finish this to find $F_Y(y)$ and differentiate to get $f_Y(y)$?

Comment: $F_Y(y)
 = \mathbb{P}[ Y \le y]
 = \mathbb{P}\left[ e^X \le y\right]
 = \mathbb{P}[ X \le \ln(y) ] = F_X(\ln(y))$ so $f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) = \frac{1}{y}f_X(\ln(y))$, right?

Comment: @Tester1998 yes

Comment: Great, thanks for hint!